# Fetus skin to normal baby skin

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

Is there a way wherein i can change a premature/unborn fetus' skin into a normal baby skin? So far what i have tried is:

- Color the skin of the fetus with skin color
- Overlayed skin texture on the skin
- Repaint/redraw skin

But it still doesn't feel right.
Here is the link of the [skin sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCbLt.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Edit: here is the sample skin for those who can't access imgur

[image]

Comment: Can you add the image to SE:GD, please, Blues, as I can't see it - it's blocked by my company's web filter.

Comment: @Paul I uploaded the photo here in SE:GD. let me know your thoughts, Thanks!

Comment: I don't think I need to say anything, really - @Alex seems to have nailed it!  ;o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi Blues – unusual question!

It looks to me like there are a couple of things you need to work on:

## Hot Spots

The fetus' skin is very shiny, so you'll need to reduce the hotspots in the image. This is a problem you'll often encounter when re-touching images shot with a direct flash – oily skin often results in big, shiny areas that need to be toned down. You can do this with the following technique:

- Select hotspots using the **Select > Colour Range** tool
- Using the **Eyedropper Tool** select a neutral skin colour by selecting some of the skin next to the hotspot
- Create a new layer
- Fill (**Option+Delete**) the selected area with the neutral skin colour
- Adjust the transparency of this layer so that the hotspots are a bit softer.

Alternatively, you can use an adjustment layer to lighten/darken the hotspots or adjust the colour balance, but I find this option is the quickest.

You can either do this step before you recolour the image, or after.

## Colour

A fetus' skin is very raw and red, whereas a baby's skin is soft and light. I'd use a combination of adjustment layers to achieve the look of soft, dry baby's skin:

**Layer > New Adjustment Layer >**

- Use **Levels** or **Brightness/Contrast** to 'soften' the contrast of the skin and reduce the dark areas.
- Use **Hue/Saturation** to desaturate the baby's skin colour
- Use **Color Balance** to change the colour of the baby's skin tone.

Obviously the way you use these adjustments will depend on the skin colour you're trying to achieve.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi @alex i manage to get the desired skin tone and by experimenting the adjustment layer steps you gave me. but do you have any ideas wherein i can somewhat achieve the slightly human skin texture? 
thanks a lot!

Comment: Also i manage to remove the hot spots